# Pointer arrays confusion

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stream, byte

Alright, so from my understanding of reading about pointer arrays:

An array is considered the equivalent of a constant pointer because it points to each of it's indexed elements. Also a pointer to an array is the equivalent as the first index's address.

Well - since this is valid:

```
int test[] = {1, 2, 3}

int * point = test;

cout << test + 2; //gives the address of the 3rd element test[2]
```

I was wondering, how come this behaves differently?

```
char arr[] = "testing pointer arrays";
char * pointer = arr;
cout << pointer + 3 << endl; //would output the actual string at pos arr[3]
```

Similarily:

```
char * test = "zomg";
cout << test + 2; //outputs mg
```

Are char pointers really special in this case? That bring me to another question regarding how in functions for streaming, you can specify how many bytes you can write/read by incrementing the point and specifying the size (such as in ofstream::write(char pointer, size);) **Furthermore, type casting a structure to a character pointer can convert it to a byte array?**

Any clarification would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Pointers are not arrays and vice-versa. They're distinct.

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html which elaborates on @chris's point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
char arr[] = "hello";
```

is equivalent to

```
char arr[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

The only difference is the meaning of a string literal such as `"hello"`, not in the way the arrays of `char` are treated c.f. those of other built-in types.

Next, when you pass a `char*` to `std::cout`

```
std::cout << pointer + 3 << endl;
```

you benefit from the fact that there is a special overload for `ostream& operator<<` for `char*`, which treats the pointer as the first element of a null-terminated string.

Comment: Well, why won't - in the case of char arrays - output the address of the variable then - as it does with integers?

Comment: @AndyCarter I added an explanation for that.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in C (and by historical reasons also in C++) a pointer to a char is considered to be in most cases a pointer to a sequence of chars terminated by the character `NUL` (written as `'\0'`).

So for example if you have a C++ function accepting an `std::string` you can also pass a pointer to a char because the language assumes that you want to do an implicit conversion from C strings (i.e. sequences of chars terminated by `NUL`) and standard C++ strings.

The output operator does the same, so when sending `test+2` it assumes you really wanted to output the C string starting from there instead.

Comment: +1 mentioning the historical C compliance rule for C string literals

Answer (score 0):

> it points to each of it's indexed elements.

you are forgetting something important about arrays, they are a data structure that is granted to be allocated in contiguos regions in memory and it contains the same type of data for each record. Considering the definition of an array the only thing that you really need to know it's where your array starts and when it ends, you don't need to point to every single record in your array because you can be sure that will be in between the begin and the end of any given array.

you example

```
int test[] = {1, 2, 3}

int * point = test;

cout << test + 2; //gives the address of the 3rd element test[2]
```

it's showing you just that but in a more cryptic way for a beginner.

`test` is an array of an unspecified size `[]`, but it got a finite list of elements, as a result the compiler is smart enough to allocate a space for `test` of 3 elements, 3 int, and the array `test` is created .

`int * point = test;` here you have test that points to the first element of your array, or in other words, **where your array begins**, `point` it's a pointer to an int, and an address it's exactly what you can feed to a pointer, so there is no error here but remember that you are passing the starting address of an array here using the label of the array `test`.

In other words `test[0]` gives you the value that is the first value in your array, `test` gives you the address of the entire array.

`test + 2` so you know that `test` it's just a placeholder for an address, now you are simply adding 2, the result is that you are skipping 2 positions and you are going right to where the third value is, but always in terms of address in memory, not in terms of value stored.

This last operation it's an example of **pointer arithmetic** and it's basically a logical operation done with simple numbers, infact due to the fact that an array is just one single contiguos block in memory, you can just count +1 or -1 to reach the next or the previous value, your problem is that there is no real boundary check for the array, so you can even go up or down so much that you reach memory addresses that are part of something else.

There is a simple example about **pointer arithmetic**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int k[] = {34,765,23,5,7,123,8,99};
  int j = 3;

  printf("\nfirst print is  %d \n",k[j]);
  printf("\nsecond print is %d \n",j[k]);

  return(0);
}
```

this is all you need to know about pointer arithmetic and remember that there is no automated boundary check, it's all in your hands!